# How to disable the Browser Cache in OpenUI5 / SAPUI5 completely

Tags: browser-cache, sapui5

Is it possible to force SAPUI5 to reload all resources from the server? For example by appending a (random) parameter to all requests (Views, Controls, etc)? I know you can make jquery append a parameter to all requests with jQuery.ajaxSetup, but this does not seem to cover all requests made by OpenUI5, since some requests are made before jquery has been loaded (such as preload libraries).

Answer (score 0):

Resources should only be loaded from server if they have been changed. To do this [Cache Buster](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/91/f080966f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070/content.htm?frameset=/en/ff/7aceda0bd24039beb9bca8e882825d/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/5c/be4e5b4a19479a92b1d32ff23b7b63/plain.htm&node_id=354) mechanism could be used.

The cache buster mechanism allows to always put the SAPUI5 resources into the browsers cache until a UI library or a web application has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge it is a server specific configuration.
If your're using xsjs, try to add the following into your .xsaccess file:

"cache_control" : "no-store"

[Docu](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/5f/e3b123826d4503aa66eb955a002821/content.htm)

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, there is no official way to achieve this goal on client only. You will need a server side solution like cache buster (mentioned by Dopedev).

However, the Ui5Strap guys wrote a hack that seem to do exactly what you want to do. It appends a fixed or random parameter to all requests made by UI5. Please note that this solution is not made for production use and can stop working on future versions of UI5.

http://ui5strap.com/docs/mods/disable-browser-cache.html